# .NET MAUI when push notification received on android in OnNewIntent the Intent.Extras are null

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/mistrypragnesh40/PushNotificationDemoMAUI). When the notification are received in the MainActivity in the overridden OnNewIntent the Intent.Extras are null, and my mobile app skips the navigation.

```
[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    private int badgeNumber = 0;

    public FirebaseService()
    {
    }

    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(token);

        if (Preferences.ContainsKey(StorageKeys.Public.GCM))
        {
            Preferences.Remove(StorageKeys.Public.GCM);
        }

        Preferences.Set(StorageKeys.Public.GCM, token);
    }

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);

        badgeNumber++;

       var notification = message.GetNotification();
       SendNotification(notification.Body, notification.Title, message.Data);
    }

    private void SendNotification(string messageBody, string title, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            var value = data[key];
            intent.PutExtra(key, value);
        }

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,MainActivity.NotificationId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.ChannelId)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetSmallIcon(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Resource.Drawable.ic_notification)
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetChannelId(MainActivity.ChannelId)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NotificationId, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static readonly string ChannelId = "BSI Notification Chanel";
    internal static readonly int NotificationId = 19780811;

    public MainActivity()
    {
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed() { }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) == Permission.Denied)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications }, 1);
        }

        CreateNotificationChanel();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent? intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        if (Intent?.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent?.Extras.KeySet() ?? [])
            {
                if (key == "NavigateTo")
                {
                    var page = Intent?.Extras.GetString(key);

                    if (Preferences.ContainsKey("NavigateTo"))
                    {
                        Preferences.Remove("NavigateTo");
                    }

                    Preferences.Set("NavigateTo", page);

                    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new PushNotificationReceivedMessage(page));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateNotificationChanel()
    {
        if (!OperatingSystem.IsOSPlatformVersionAtLeast("android", 26))
        {
            return;
        }

        var channel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelId, "BSI Notification Chanel", NotificationImportance.Default);
        
        var manager = (NotificationManager?)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        manager?.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly SecurityService securityService;
    private readonly UserService userService;

    public App(SecurityService securityService, UserService userService)
    {
        this.securityService = securityService;
        this.userService = userService;

        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SplashPage());

        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<PushNotificationReceivedMessage>(this, async (r, m) =>
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(m.Value);
        });
```

}
}

Anyone with the same issue, and how can I resolve this?
Another thing is that when the app is not running, or it is in the background the notifications are not received.

thnx

Comment: Did you test the sample in the link you provided?

Comment: I am unable to start it.

Comment: According to the [code link you provided](https://github.com/mistrypragnesh40/PushNotificationDemoMAUI/blob/37bb11b5fb490bb8d84cc9c132c961196f753738/Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs#L33), it should be `intent` not `Intent`.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT you have a hawk eye. I did not noticed it. Will try. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure. Is the  problem fixed now?